# .corr() - Correlation ignores columns with numeric data

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation

I am trying to use `df.corr()` on a DataFrame and it is not returning correlation for all columns. Interestingly, it ignores the columns which are grey.
[Screen shot of DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvyZc.png)

I assign value to the 'grey' columns like that (with a for loop going through `m`):

```
Result_ARES.at[Result_ARES.NORAD==m,'popt0'] = popt[0]
```

I thought it might be a type issue. But `type(popt[0])` is a `numpy.float64`.

Any ideas what I can do to rectify this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'data' in the column might have been a float but it was indexed as an object.
The solution was to change all datatypes to `float64` using this line of code:

```
Result_ARES = Result_ARES.astype('float64')
```